# I have an error on 'print[str]' in swift, stating that 'ambiguous reference to member 'print(separator:terminator:)'

Tags: swift

I have an error on `print[str]` in Swift, stating that

> ambiguous reference to member 'print(separator:terminator:)'

```
import UIKit

var str = "Test"

print(str)
```

[image]

Comment: Everything works fine. I've just checked it in the playground.

Comment: It doesn't for me. Is there a way I could send you a screenshot?

Comment: Add screenshot into your question.

Comment: I believe I have added it. Can you see it?

Answer (score 1):

On the screenshot you use `print[str]` instead of `print(str)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really sorry, but I'm new to swift and have been looking hours for the solution. I feel slightly silly for not checking that, but I'm happy I got a response.

Comment: @JanCowell, it is Ok, it happens ;]